# Specify parameter that contains a dot in its name using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

With Python, how can I implement the following R statement using `rpy2`?

```
library(climatol)
homogen('Vel',2011,2012,tinc='6 hour',expl=TRUE,dz.max=10)
```

The following code in Python has worked for all parameters except `dz.max`.

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr('climatol')

r['homogen']('Vel',2011,2012,tinc='6 hour',expl=r['as.logical']('T'))
```

I see that I can call R functions using `r[<function_name>]` regardless of whether they have a dot in their name, for example `as.logical`, which I used to invoke the boolean value `True`. Now how can I specify parameters whose name contains dots, as in the case of `dz.max`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
climatol = importr('climatol')
climatol.homogen('Vel', 2011, 2012, tinc='6 hour', expl=True, dz_max=10)
```

Consider checking the documentation, for example the introduction:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/introduction.html